# DPM 2010 Synchronisation with Exchange leads to odd error in Exchange Server Log

Tags: exchange-2007, scdpm

On each DPM synchronisation the following errors are logged on the exchange server

```
Unable to update Mailbox SD in the DS. Mailbox Guid: 2ad8687a-a049-4db2-b8c2-86b493495c20. Error Code 0x8004010f 

Unable to update Mailbox SD in the DS. Mailbox Guid: 03be3109-83b4-45da-8695-8f32371cb0bd. Error Code 0x8004010f
```

Error:0x8004010f translates as NOT_FOUND

the full event is:

```
Event Type: Warning 
Event Source:   MSExchangeIS 
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   9554 
Date:    02/11/2010 
Time:    15:40:07 
User:    N/A 
Computer:   BMCEX01 
Description: 
Unable to update Mailbox SD in the DS. Mailbox Guid: 2ad8687a-a049-4db2-b8c2-86b493495c20. Error Code 0x8004010f
```

I've used the adfind tool to try and identify them:

```
adfind -gc -b "" -binenc -f " msExchMailboxGUID={{GUID:2ad8687a-a049-4db2-b8c2-86b493495c20}}" -dn
```

But that returns no records.

So how do I determine what is causing the error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as soon as you ask the question you make the leap that you haven't for days...

Open an exchange powershell... and run:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | where-object { $_.DisconnectDate -ne $null } | Select DisplayName,MailboxGuid
```

and there are my two accounts. I have no need of them and so I can run:

```
$users = Get-MailboxStatistics | where-object { $_.DisconnectDate -ne $null } | Select DisplayName,MailboxGuid
$users | ForEach { Remove-Mailbox -Database "Mailbox Database" -StoreMailboxIdentity $_.MailboxGuid -confirm:$false }
```

Luckily I didn't have to think to construct those powershell commands. Once I'd had the inspiration my google-fu got me to [this blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/andersonpatricio/archive/2007/10/08/removing-disconnected-mailboxes-in-exchange-server-2007.aspx).